# Peculiar ASP.NET Error Message

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, asp.net-ajax

This is displayed as a client message ("Error on page.") in the status bar.  I think at this point, the app is using some kind of AJAX callback in response to a login button.

Trying to deploy on a new Windows Server 2008 testbed (runs fine in debugger and has been deployed on Windows Server 2003, but we're trying to upgrade our testbed and production images for future installations.)

Where do I go next to track down the root cause?

Webpage error details

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; GTB6.6; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; MDDR; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; MS-RTC LM 8; AskTbARS/5.11.3.15590)
Timestamp: Tue, 22 Mar 2011 18:24:57 UTC


Message: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched.  Inaccessible logs: Security.
Line: 5
Char: 62099
Code: 0
URI: http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/ScriptResource.axd?d=h-4WZuFBCcT-1QOz27ZRxMnCrM1dJDc_fETsNUPAfsPgng_3pAoC80eScNiAc9AAVaTQPonQz7cMCVz6SHzZIJ0Tvj-YmVHBRaokQGWQIKRz7KO0y6B7UKgccbT4YFzWqhNPS7kUsVnHQX2F9zBJAK9qeEI1&t=40fa519
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a shot in the dark, but it might be that the ASP.NET AJAX resources aren't loaded on the new server. I vaguely remember having the same issue a year or so ago and, IIRC, I had to load the .NET Framework 2.0 AJAX libraries on the server.

Comment: Thanks, but .NET 3.5 is installed and it looks like the site is targets 3.5, so AJAX libraries should all be there.

Comment: Ok, so it rules out that possibility... I'll dig a bit further and see what I can come up with.

Comment: Just another guess - is your ASP.NET registered with IIS? Have you run the "aspnet_regiis.exe -i" command from the particular .NET Framework version yet? Seeing as it's 3.5, which piggy-backs on 2.0, you should register 2.0.

Comment: After reboot, I'm getting something more useful about the app not being able to connect to the (Oracle) database, which is a start.  Problem is, I don't know if it was the application pool or the aspnet_regiis...

Comment: Well, at least you're getting somewhere. Glad you're making progress at least! There's nothing worse than fiddling around on a server with the bare minimum amount of error detail...

Comment: I'm thinking that aspnet_regiis.exe was the culprit.  Why would that not be done by default?

Comment: This is an app which is about 100x more convoluted than it needs to be.

Comment: And we're down to uncompiled Oracle objects - but at least it's application logged errors, no matter how many places I had to look...

Comment: I've realized that installing IIS on a fresh server installation necessitates the registration of the .NET framework on it. Even though .NET was shipped with the server installation, you still need to register it. That's my experience with it anyway...

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess. Maybe it's being run on IIS7 now, and the configuration is different for IIS7. If you are just trying to get it working, in IIS7 server settings, trying switching your application pool to from Integrated Mode to Classic Mode.

Comment: Didn't seem to have any effect.  Rebooting machine now to see if that's necessary.

Comment: After reboot, I'm getting something more useful about the app not being able to connect to the (Oracle) database, which is a start.  Problem is, I don't know if it was the application pool or the aspnet_regiis...